# How to manage sqlalchemy model migration in fastapi

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic

I have used **fastapi** for project facing issue with **sqlachemy** model

**sqlachemy** create model first time but when we change in model not affect on postgres database.
Overcome this problem.

- I have used **alembic** package for handle model migration it's work in adding new column and removing column but does not work in altering column like rename columns name, change datatype etc.
- When I rename columns name it's create upgrade opration is droping an existing column and add new one with new name *(loss of data)*

like: rename **is_superuser** to **is_admin**

```
def upgrade():
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    op.add_column("user", sa.Column("is_admin", sa.Boolean(), nullable=True))
    op.drop_column("user", "is_superuser")
    # ### end Alembic commands ###
```

see what's going on droping **is_superuser** column inted of rename

> I know the tricky solution is custom adding action in migration
> `op.alter_column('table_name','column_name',new_column_name='new column name')`

> How to handle model migration with sqlalchemy in fastapi because if i will make mistake in alembic migration it would be denger for me.

Is there any other package or way to handle migration with **sqlalchemy**

Comment: It's been a while since I last used alembic, but I believe detecting column type changes is an [optional setting](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/autogenerate.html#what-does-autogenerate-detect-and-what-does-it-not-detect)

Comment: Thanks, @HeddevanderHeide is there any package for handle migration in fastapi

Comment: A solution would be running a two step migration, where you add a column with a different name, copy the data from the column to rename, then delete the original column. I frequently do this because I feel more in control and it's probably safer.

Comment: You can use [alembic](https://youtu.be/N9y9QkBM-Aw) for database migrations.

Comment: Yes I had used that and then raise the question.

Answer (score 1):

> use case: rename column from `is_superuser` to `is_admin` in the table `user`

### 1. using alembic operations

For the above case, we can write the migration like below.

```py
def upgrade():
    op.alter_column('user', 'is_superuser', nullable=True, new_column_name='is_admin')
```

Now, run the command `alembic upgrade head --sql` to see the actual `SQL` that will be applied on the databse.

```sql
ALTER TABLE user RENAME is_superuser TO is_admin;
```

### 2. using custom SQL

```py
def upgrade():
    op.execute('ALTER TABLE user RENAME is_superuser TO is_admin;')
```

> run command `alembic upgrade head` to apply the migration on the database.

### Reference:

- https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/ops.html#alembic.operations.Operations.alter_column
- [getting started with alembic](https://learnbatta.com/blog/getting-started-with-alembic/#why-alembic)
- [alembic DDL operations](https://learnbatta.com/blog/alembic-ddl-operations/#rename-table-column-with-alembic)

Comment: Yes I had used that and then raise the question. Is there any package or way I am asking about.

Comment: as per the [docs](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/ops.html#alembic.operations.Operations.alter_column) those are the only two ways for now.